# How can I simultaneously delete all sections, in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

The screenshot beneath shows only an option to delete each section, which is too unproductive.

[image]

Comment: Why not make a new notebook?  If you can Edit to explain what you're trying to accomplish, it might make the answer more apparent.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Do you mean deleting this notebook and creating a new one? This feels more inefficient than just deleting all the sections.

Comment: It's not more inefficient. Have you tried creating a new Notebook? It's a trivial process involving not more than 3 clicks and resulting in a clean, empty notebook.

Comment: @music2myear I see now. But is there truly no option to delete all sections simultaneously?

Comment: As you have observed from your own perusal of the UI, there is not.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in method to delete all sections in a OneNote notebook. Microsoft developers did not, apparently, believe this was likely to be a normal desire, as, correctly, they assumed a person doing this would probably find it easier to simply create a new Notebook.

Because OneNote uses the excellent VBA macro system, it is possible to write code to delete all of sections in a Notebook, but the effort required to do this would exceed both the normal manual deletion of each section and the much simpler process of creating a new notebook.

Incidentally, the steps to create a new notebook are:

1. Open the **File** section.
2. Click **New**
3. Enter a name for your new notebook
4. Click the **Create Notebook** button

The steps to close your old notebook are:

1. In the list of notebooks on the left side of the OneNote UI, right-click on the notebook you wish to remove.
2. Click **Close this notebook**
3. (optional) Find the folder belonging to this notebook in your Documents\Notebooks directory and delete it.